# Okay to POST with an empty body, pass data in the response?

Tags: http, post

I want a client to be able to request (via HTTP) whichever document is at the head of a server's output queue, with the understanding that if retrieval is successful, the document will then automatically be deleted from the queue. There is never more than one client per server, but the client could be multithreaded. There is no random access to the queue; only the head item can be retrieved (and deleted). I have not found this scenario discussed either here or elsewhere on the web. Here are the various approaches I can think of:

(1) The client could send a GET request. But GET is not supposed to have side effects, so this doesn't seem like a good idea.

(2) The client could send two requests, a GET to retrieve the document at the head of the queue and a DELETE (with an empty or ignorable URL) to delete the document at the head of the queue. But this requires two calls, which could cause various problems, especially if more than one thread/process in the client is trying to retrieve files.

(3) The client could send a POST request with an empty body; if there is a document at the head of the queue, the server will return a response whose body contains the document, and will also delete the document from the queue. This is somewhat counterintuitive in that it doesn't match the mental model of posting data and receiving a simple return code, but otherwise I like it. I'm not worried about the response getting lost in transit and the document going missing; I expect the connection to be safe enough to prevent this.

It would be nice if there were another HTTP method to handle this situation, but since there isn't, I think (3) is the best approach. Agree? Disagree?

UPDATE: Added (4) after reading Dan675's post below.

(4) The client could send a DELETE request, to which the server could send a response with the document in the body (and delete the document from the queue, of course). Again, this is slightly counterintuitive (you don't usually say "delete the item on top of the stack for me, please" when you want to retrieve it), but would work.

Comment: Is the URL always going to be the same, but with a different document every "action"?

Comment: Yes, the URL will always be the same, and yes, the document should be different each time (unless the same one gets submitted to the input queue multiple times, which we couldn't prevent).

Comment: I agree that 1) is the simplest, but semantically incorrect, 2) is correct but is more complicated to implement, and 3) is a good compromise, but is still semantically incorrect.

Comment: I think I'm going to use option 4.

Answer (score 1):

It should be done in two calls the first to GET it then one to DELETE it.

If the delete succeeds then the clients request is valid otherwise just treat it as if the whole request failed and try to get what's on the top of the queue again. This will cause some additional overhead due to failed requests but I would not recommend doing either of the other options.

I guess another way of doing this would be to first maybe do a PUT to mark the top most item as 'reserved' in some way then do a GET and DELETE. In doing it this way it may be possible to traverse this server side queue and look for the top-most item that is not 'reserved'.

Comment: +1 PUT it on the reserved queue, GET it from the reserved queue and then DELETE it from the reserved queue. Nice idea.

Comment: It seems that your are concerned with the speed of operation and do not want to introduce overhead with these suggestions so I would say your new option, number 4 would be the most valid.

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering what reserving the item, either on the existing queue or on a separate one, will buy us, especially since only the topmost item should be accessible. Once a document has been retrieved, I know it can be deleted.

Comment: It stops your option 2 from potentially having problems due to more than one process/thread using it at once. Yet keeps the client's busy  as you are not having to keep retrieving from the top of the queue if the item has already been deleted by another process/thread.